# What can I use to generate API documentation with my custom formatting?

Tags: java, documentation, automation

I want to automatically generate documentation for a java project, but I'd like to have my own custom styling for it.

As an example, take the [stackoverflow api (method description page)](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/answers), can that be done by an automated tool? Can it "take me close" to that?
I wouldn't mind having to manually change a few things to achieve the result I want (ie: it doesn't have to be 100% automated)

Comment: NaturalDocs and Doxygen are pretty configurable. I admit I never really stray past the default formatting because it's usually good enough, but it's probably possible.

Comment: Doxygen seems pretty good, have you used that one? Did you have any problems?

Comment: I used it a long time ago for C++ (not Java). It was good, but I didn't try any customization, just ran it "out-of-the-box" and it was good enough. I haven't looked, but maybe you can even customize the output of `javadoc`, might be as simple as an XSL or CSS file... EDIT: here ya go! http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doxygen and NaturalDocs are both customizable alternatives to Javadoc. Javadoc can also be customized, as is described here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/javadoc/overview.html

...though be warned, I have never attempted this myself, I only found it via web search for "javadoc customize output".

Answer (score 1):

As Frustrated notes, a [Doclet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html) allows you to customize the the existing Javadoc mechanisms. Doing "Javadoc with a twist" probably has some benefits in terms of IDE integration too.

In particular, given the use of markdown on stackexchange sites, you may want ot see [this one that handles markdown](http://code.google.com/p/markdown-doclet/), which may be some useful code to look at even if it isn't the formatting rules you want.